# How do I align elements using CSS?

Tags: css, html, html5boilerplate

I'm trying to display the ***arrows and images on the same line***. How do I achieve that? (I'm using html5boilerplate).

### What I need:

[image]

### What I have now:

[image]

### Current code:

#### HTML:

```html
    <div id="linkbar">
        <a><img src="./img/arrowleft.png"></a>
        <div id="linkbarinternal">
            <ul>
                <li><a><img src="./img/banner01.jpg"></a></li>
                <li><a><img src="./img/banner02.jpg"></a></li>
                <li><a><img src="./img/banner03.jpg"></a></li>
                <li><a><img src="./img/banner04.jpg"></a></li>
                <li><a><img src="./img/banner05.jpg"></a></li>
                <li><a><img src="./img/banner06.jpg"></a></li>
                <li><a><img src="./img/banner07.jpg"></a></li>
                <li><a><img src="./img/banner08.jpg"></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <a><img src="./img/arrowright.png"></a>
    </div>
```

#### CSS:

```css
#linkbar {
    width:90%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    clear: both;
}

#linkbarinternal {
    border-top:2px solid #aa0000;
    border-bottom:2px solid #aa0000;
    width: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

#linkbar ul, #linkbar li {
    display: inline;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Comment: did you try `overflow: hidden;` ?

Comment: set a width on linkbarinternal for overflow:hidden to work.

Comment: @SamR. Yes, doesn't seem to affect the alignment issue. Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: @ChristopherMarshall It was working on both chrome and firefox without a width explicitly set. I did set one now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `box-sizing:border-box`
2. You might need to remove whitespace around elements to get those tight fits right.
3. #linkbarinternal need to have `display: inline-block;`

You will also have to work on margins and padding and/or height of elements.

Comment: Thanks. Also I wasn't aware of `box-sizing`, thanks for the new info!